# How do I get the URI that threw a WebException?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, uri, system.net.webexception

I'm calling a method on a webservice and it is throwing a 403 Forbidden WebException...

> System.Net.WebException: The request
>   failed with HTTP status 403:
>   Forbidden.

I've got this error logged but I'd really like to have the URI recorded in the log message so it is easy to determine which webservice is causing the problem.

Is there a simple way to get the URI from the WebException that is thrown? I've looked through the list of properties and I can't see anything that will get me what I want.

Comment: shouldn't you have to URI to make the call?

Comment: My method makes use of two webservices which can both throw a WebException....As such, I'd like to have access to the URI from the exception...

Comment: So you're calling 2 webservice methods from within your own webservice?

Comment: I've got one application that makes use of two webservices...

Comment: Just wrap them with a try..catch and throw your own custom exception, with the Url details in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the `Url` property on your SOAP client proxy object (`SoapHttpClientProtocol` type).

If you're calling two different web services from one method in your code, simply put a try {} catch around the web service calls and throw an appropriate custom `Exception` with the Url property of the offending web service.

Something like:

```
string url = client.Url;
try
{
  client.MyWebServiceCall();
  url = client2.Url;
  client2.MyWebServiceCall2();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  throw new Exception("Webservice call failed. Url: "+url+", Error:"+ex.Message,ex);
}
```

Comment: I'm marking this one as the answer because I didn't realise the webservice had access to a Url property...and since my code had a wrapper around the webservice which didn't replicate the Url I had no access to it. I've change my code to give the Url on the wrapped webservice and made sure my try-catch is only around one service call.

Answer (score 0):

Be certain you are not making the call to the service through an authentication-required webproxy. You will get this (or perhaps a 401) error and pull your hair out (as I did) trying to figure out where the failure is occurring. I didn't realize what was happening until I did a network trace and found the requests were hitting our outbound authenticated proxy, and the request had no credentials, and bounced back.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to retrieve the Uri directly from a WebException:

```
Uri uri = wex.Response.ResponseUri;
```